# How to create an infinite rain of icons in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to create an infinite rain of icons in Flutter. Let me explain.

Here is the widget that will be performing the raining/falling animation. It uses an AnimationController along with a GravitySimulation to make the widget fall. It takes in an `endDistance`, which is how far it should go down. It renders a simple icon (also an argument).

```
import 'package:clickr/providers/GameEngineProvider.dart';
import 'package:clickr/utils/functions/randInt.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class FallingIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final double endDistance;
  final double? iconLeft;
  final double? iconRight;
  final double? iconBottom;
  final Widget? child;

  const FallingIcon({
    Key? key,
    required this.endDistance,
    this.iconLeft,
    this.iconRight,
    this.iconBottom,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FallingIconState createState() => _FallingIconState();
}

class _FallingIconState extends State<FallingIcon>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(
        milliseconds: randInt(2000, 3000),
      ),
    );

    _controller.animateWith(
      GravitySimulation(
        10,
        0,
        widget.endDistance,
        0,
      ),
    );

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Positioned(
          child: child!,
          top: _controller.value * widget.endDistance,
          left: widget.iconLeft,
          right: widget.iconRight,
          bottom: widget.iconBottom,
        );
      },
      child: widget.child ?? const FlutterLogo(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I am using this widget inside a stack:

```
import 'package:clickr/providers/GameEngineProvider.dart';
import 'package:clickr/providers/IconSetsProvider.dart';
import 'package:clickr/screens/HomeScreen.Authenticated.dart';
import 'package:clickr/widgets/CircleSticker.dart';
import 'package:clickr/widgets/FallingIcon.dart';
import 'package:clickr/widgets/StatusBarSpacer.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../widgets/FloatingActionButtonCustomBar.dart';

class PlayScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = "/play";

  @override
  State<PlayScreen> createState() => _PlayScreenState();
}

class _PlayScreenState extends State<PlayScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final iconSetsProvider =
        Provider.of<IconSetsProvider>(context, listen: false);

    final gameEngineProvider =
        Provider.of<GameEngineProvider>(context, listen: true);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const StatusBarSpacer(),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    FallingIcon(
                      endDistance: constraints.maxHeight,
                      child: Image.asset(
                          iconSetsProvider.getRandomIconFromIconSet(
                            iconSetsProvider.currentIconSet!,
                          ),
                          width: 40,
                        ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          FloatingActionButtonCustomBar(
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
                      HomeScreenAuthenticatated.routeName);
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.home),
                heroTag: "home",
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                heroTag: "pause",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code renders **one** FallingIcon, which successfully animates and falls until it reaches the end of the screen and cannot be seen any more. Now, I want to multiply this icon, so there should be multiple icons falling on the screen. And I want this to never stop. It should just be an infinite rain of icons. And it shouldn't be systematic, like one wave after the other. It should just be random infinite rain of icons.

I have attempted to use a stream and a new event would be pushed onto the stream randomly. But then I couldn't figure out how to render FallingIcons based on the items in the stream.

I wonder if this is possible in Flutter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

this kind of "raining/falling animation" could be implemented with one `CustomPaint` widget (instead of rebuilding lots of widgets with `AnimatedBuilder`)

the core idea is to provide a `Listenable` variable to `CustomPainter.repaint` property (see `super(repaint: ...)` below) - of course you need to change your `CustomPainter` so that it draws your vertically falling images

```
class FooSpritePaint extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FooSpritePaint> createState() => _FooSpritePaintState();
}

class _FooSpritePaintState extends State<FooSpritePaint> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Ticker ticker;
  final notifier = ValueNotifier(Duration.zero);
  ui.Image? sprite;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ticker = Ticker(_tick);
    rootBundle.load('images/sprites.png')
      .then((data) => decodeImageFromList(data.buffer.asUint8List()))
      .then(_setSprite);
  }

  _tick(Duration d) => notifier.value = d;

  _setSprite(ui.Image image) {
    setState(() {
      // print('image: $image');
      sprite = image;
      ticker.start();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: SpritePainter(sprite, notifier),
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () => ticker.isTicking? ticker.stop() : ticker.start(),
            child: const Text('click to stop / start', textScaleFactor: 1.5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SpritePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image? sprite;
  final ValueNotifier<Duration> notifier;
  final p = Paint();

  SpritePainter(this.sprite, this.notifier) : super(repaint: notifier);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.clipRect(Offset.zero & size);
    if (sprite != null) {
      final ms = notifier.value.inMilliseconds;
      final frame = ms ~/ 80;
      // print(frame);
      final frames = [frame, frame + 2, frame + 4].map((f) => f % 6).toList();
      final spritePhases = [
        phase(size.width, ms * 0.066),
        phase(size.width, ms * 0.075 + 40),
        phase(size.width, ms * 0.075 + 80),
      ];
      final transforms = [
        for (int i = 0; i < spritePhases.length; i++)
          ui.RSTransform(1, 0, spritePhases[i][0], size.height / 2 - 45),
      ];
      final rects = [
        for (int i = 0; i < spritePhases.length; i++)
          Rect.fromLTWH(frames[i] * 100, spritePhases[i][1] * 100, 100, 100),
      ];
      canvas.drawAtlas(sprite!, transforms, rects, null, null, null, p);
    }
  }

  List<double> phase(double width, double x) {
    final w = width + 100;
    x = x % (2 * w);
    return x < w? [x - 100, 0] : [2 * w - x - 100, 1];
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(SpritePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

the above sample code uses the following image that should be placed in `images/sprites.png` folder:

[image]

**EDIT**

and as a proof of concept here you have such a sample `CustomPainter`:

```
class Bird {
  Bird(int ms, this.rect, List<double> r, Size size) :
    startTimeMs = ms,
    scale = lerpDouble(1, 0.3, r[0])!,
    rotation = pi * lerpDouble(-1, 1, r[2])!,
    xSimulation = FrictionSimulation(0.75, r[1] * size.width, lerpDouble(size.width / 2, -size.width / 2, r[1])!),
    ySimulation = GravitySimulation(lerpDouble(10, 1000, r[0])!, -rect.height / 2, size.height + rect.height / 2, 100);

  final int startTimeMs;
  final Rect rect;
  final Simulation xSimulation;
  final Simulation ySimulation;
  final double scale;
  final double rotation;

  double x(int ms) => xSimulation.x(_normalizeTime(ms));

  double y(int ms) => ySimulation.x(_normalizeTime(ms));

  bool isDead(int ms) => ySimulation.isDone(_normalizeTime(ms));

  double _normalizeTime(int ms) => (ms - startTimeMs) / Duration.millisecondsPerSecond;

  RSTransform transform(int ms, Size size) {
    final translateY = y(ms);
    return RSTransform.fromComponents(
      translateX: x(ms),
      translateY: translateY,
      anchorX: rect.width / 2,
      anchorY: rect.height / 2,
      rotation: rotation * translateY / size.height,
      scale: scale,
    );
  }
}

class FallingBirdsPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image? sprite;
  final ValueNotifier<Duration> notifier;
  final imagePaint = Paint();
  final backgroundPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.black26;
  final random = Random();
  final birds = <Bird>[];
  int nextReport = 0;

  static const spriteRects = [
    Rect.fromLTRB(000, 0, 103, 140),
    Rect.fromLTRB(103, 0, 217, 140),
    Rect.fromLTRB(217, 0, 312, 140),
    Rect.fromLTRB(312, 0, 410, 140),
  ];

  FallingBirdsPainter(this.sprite, this.notifier) : super(repaint: notifier);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.clipRect(Offset.zero & size);
    canvas.drawPaint(backgroundPaint);
    if (sprite != null) {
      final ms = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      if (random.nextDouble() < 0.15) {
        // drop new bird
        birds.add(Bird(ms, spriteRects[random.nextInt(4)], List.generate(3, (i) => random.nextDouble()), size));
      }

      final transforms = birds.map((bird) => bird.transform(ms, size)).toList();
      final rects = birds.map((bird) => bird.rect).toList();
      canvas.drawAtlas(sprite!, transforms, rects, null, null, null, imagePaint);

      // dead birds cleanup
      birds.removeWhere((bird) => bird.isDead(ms));

      if (ms >= nextReport) {
        nextReport = ms + 6000;
        print('flying birds population: ${birds.length}');
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FallingBirdsPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

it uses the following image:

[image]

all you need is to replace

```
foregroundPainter: SpritePainter(sprite, notifier),
```

with

```
foregroundPainter: FallingBirdsPainter(sprite, notifier),
```

and

```
rootBundle.load('images/sprites.png')
```

with

```
rootBundle.load('images/birds.png')
```

the final result is similar to this:

[image]

Comment: excuse me sir, can you kindly explain to me what this line mean  `frame = ms ~/ 80;` , and why it value 80? its equal to 60 fps or something like that?

Comment: @SayyidJ try to change 80 to 40 or 160 or 300 and compare the results - it is a simple factor for speed controlling

Comment: thank you sir, your code is amazing, barely know it custom painter is extends Listenable

Comment: @SayyidJ thanks a lot, btw did you try "falling birds" second sample?

Comment: not yet, but that a lot of effort to calculate all that logic, such a shame this gem is sink in this question, you should make a youtube channel sir, it will be a hit