# How to build flutter real time graph?

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, charts

I tried many times with Syncfusion but it is lagging a lot for me and from my tests it looks overloaded. Also I noticed

I have seen mp_chart but it doesn't look like it's supported anymore

All I need is very simple real time chart with 2 lines which can be refreshed without lags like 2-4 times per sec

Comment: it seems you need a `CustomPaint` widget then

Comment: hello, do you know from what source I can learn that?

Comment: you need to learn [Canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) API first, and for `CustomPainter` "refreshing" check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332956/how-to-create-an-infinite-rain-of-icons-in-flutter/71347939#71347939) - pay attention to `repaint: ...` passed in calling `super` constructor - it can be any `Listenable` like `ValueNotifier`, `AnimationController` etc