# flutter pixelation of resizing of ui.image using canvas.drawAtlas

Tags: flutter, image, canvas, pixel

I have a image that I draw to a canvas and then I resize the canvas using Transform.scale. This creates pixelation of image. How can I remove this pixelation?

I have tried to resize the image when I load it and that has the same effect.

I want to be able to scale the image because I am creating a map with these tick and filter marks on them so I need to be able to zoom in and out on the canvas. And I cannot use the Image widget.

This is how I am currently doing it

1. Loading the into a widget using a custom painter

```
Image? tickFilterImage8xV2;

 
class tick_filter_layer extends StatelessWidget {
  const tick_filter_layer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(painter: LayerBoundaryBoxDetails(context: context));
  }
}

class LayerBoundaryBoxDetails extends CustomPainter {
  final BuildContext context;

  LayerBoundaryBoxDetails({required this.context});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (tickFilterImage8xV2 != null) {
      List<RSTransform> transforms = [];
      List<Rect> rects = [];
      Paint paint = Paint();
      paint.color = QCIColours.red;
      // testing we just draw a single image

      // create the test transforms and rects
      rects.add(const Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 480, 240));
      transforms.add(RSTransform.fromComponents(
          rotation: 0,
          scale: 1,
          anchorX: 0,
          anchorY: 0,
          translateX: 0,
          translateY: 300));
      canvas.drawAtlas(
          tickFilterImage8xV2!, transforms, rects, null, null, null, paint);
    } else {
      loadAsset(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LayerBoundaryBoxDetails oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(LayerBoundaryBoxDetails oldDelegate) => false;

  /// this should always load
  static Future loadAsset(BuildContext context) async {
    // this image is 480 by 240
    tickFilterImage8xV2 = await getUiImage('lib/assets/tick_and_filter_8x.png');
  }

  static Future<ui.Image?> getUiImage(String assetPath) async {
    /// load the asset from the rootBundle (AssetBundle)
    final ByteData assetImageByteData = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
    final codec =
        await ui.instantiateImageCodec(assetImageByteData.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    return image;
  }
}
```

2. displaying the Custom drawer at different scale

```
Stack (
children: [
                        Transform.scale(
                            scale: 1 / 1, child: const tick_filter_layer()),
                        Transform.scale(
                            scale: 1 / 2, child: const tick_filter_layer()),
                        Transform.scale(
                            scale: 1 / 4, child: const tick_filter_layer()),
                        Transform.scale(
                            scale: 1 / 8, child: const tick_filter_layer()),
                        Transform.scale(
                            scale: 1 / 16, child: const tick_filter_layer()),
                        Transform.scale(
                            scale: 1 / 32, child: const tick_filter_layer()),
]
);
```

And the resulting screen shot with different zoom levels.

[image: image showing the different scale]

Comment: I have not looked at paintImage but I need to do max 8000 of these image hence I was wanting to use atlas draw because I believe this would be optimal. I will check out paintImage, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: sorry I don't get it, you need to draw 8000 scaled images? what do you need `TransTransform.scale` then? and if you want `drawAtlas` why don't you change `scale: 1,` to your scale factor (and removing `Transform.scale`)?

Comment: I need to draw a max of 8000 images (ticks and filters icons as above) onto a canvas that I then scale using  Transform.scale. 
I'm rendering a floor plan and on that floor plan things can be selected. I use the canvas as my floor and then I zoom and pan using transform.
Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: what i don't understand is why don't you draw your image with different scale factor directly (for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332956/how-to-create-an-infinite-rain-of-icons-in-flutter#71347939 - the second code snippet)

Comment: there are two options for rendering the floor and contents
1) render onto a canvas and then scale and translate for panning. Means that I deal with one canvas, or as 
2) you say scale the tick (or filter) image and then add it to the screen, at the location that is found using the current zoom and pan.

both achieve the same final result but the scaling of this tick (or filter) image is still the key point. I cannot seem to do this without pixelation. and I need to keep in mind that I might do 8000 of these image and render them.

Comment: which results in:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ2BA.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248870/discussion-between-paul-cardno-and-pskink).

Comment: if you insist in using `Transform.scale` use `filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium` then, or when using `drawAtlas` with different scaling factor set `Paint.filterQuality`

Comment: thanks pskink both of those work well. Appreciate the feedback.