# Is it possible to render 1-2 thousand images in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

I am using Flutter to develop a game. I would like to display 1-2 thousand small images that can move (via a AnimatedPositioned widget for example) on the screen. The resolution will be very low of each individual image of course. I'm unsure if Fluttter has a feature or is able to handle such a feature and would like to know if it's possible, and if so, best method to get there.

I've tried displaying 1000 images using Image.asset('my_image.PNG') in a GridView.builder(), using the profiler, my emulator was only able to achieve 6fps average.

Comment: why you need to render 1k images?

Comment: Lower the resolution of your images to the bare minimum that's needed. That's a lot of images. You don't want to have to load all that extra image data only for it be be thrown away when you make the image super tiny.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71347939/2252830