# I need to add image to canvas from CellPainter class [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, canvas

I use CellPainter class to prepare data and show on one canvas lines, dots, square... and that part of code working good as below:

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:math' as math;
    import 'dart:ui' as ui;
    import 'dart:typed_data';

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
    import 'package:r_b_reader/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
    import 'package:r_b_reader/model/xml_model.dart';

    class GraphicsClass {
      static Widget createCellWidget(Kratka cell, BuildContext context) {
        return CustomPaint(
      painter: CellPainter(cell, context),
        );
      }
    }

    class CellPainter extends CustomPainter {
    final Kratka cell;
    final BuildContext context;

    CellPainter(this.cell, this.context);

    final darkMode = FlutterFlowTheme.themeMode.name == "dark";

    @override
    Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    final width = 100.0;
    final height = 100.0;

    final paint = ui.Paint()
      ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;
    paint.color = darkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black;

    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, width, height);
    final borderRadius = Radius.circular(10.0);
    final roundedRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      rect,
      topLeft: borderRadius,
      topRight: borderRadius,
      bottomLeft: borderRadius,
      bottomRight: borderRadius,
    );
    canvas.drawRRect(roundedRect, paint);

    for (final el in cell.cellElements!) {
      //WARSTWY pod innymi
      if (el.type != 9 && el.type != 4 && el.type != 5) {
        //
        if (el.type == 0) {
          //RYSOWANIE linii ciągłej i strzałki
          final ltA = countLeftTop(width, height, el.startAnchorId);
          final ltB = countLeftTop(width, height, el.endAnchorId);
          paint.color = darkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
          paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;

          // Oryginalna długość linii
          final originalLineLength = math.sqrt(
              math.pow(ltB.dx - ltA.dx, 2) + math.pow(ltB.dy - ltA.dy, 2));

          // Wartość do dodania lub odjęcia od długości linii
          final lineLengthModifier = -1.0; // Wartość można dostosować

          // Obliczamy nową długość linii
          final newLineLength = originalLineLength + lineLengthModifier;

          // Obliczamy wektor linii
          final lineVector = ltB - ltA;

          // Normalizujemy wektor linii do jednostkowej długości
          final normalizedLineVector = lineVector / originalLineLength;

          // Obliczamy przesunięty punkt końcowy linii
          final lineEnd = ltA + normalizedLineVector * newLineLength;

          // Rysowanie linii
          final linePath = Path();
          linePath.moveTo(ltA.dx, ltA.dy);
          linePath.lineTo(lineEnd.dx, lineEnd.dy);
          canvas.drawPath(linePath, paint);

          // Rysowanie strzałki
          final arrowPath = Path();
          arrowPath.moveTo(lineEnd.dx, lineEnd.dy);

          final angle = math.atan2(lineEnd.dy - ltA.dy, lineEnd.dx - ltA.dx);
          final arrowLength = 5.0;

          final arrowPoint1 = Offset(
            lineEnd.dx - math.cos(angle + math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
            lineEnd.dy - math.sin(angle + math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
          );
          final arrowPoint2 = Offset(
            lineEnd.dx - math.cos(angle - math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
            lineEnd.dy - math.sin(angle - math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
          );

          arrowPath.lineTo(arrowPoint1.dx, arrowPoint1.dy);
          arrowPath.lineTo(arrowPoint2.dx, arrowPoint2.dy);
          arrowPath.close();

          canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);
        }
        if (el.type == 1) {
          //RYSOWANIE linii przerywanej i strzałki
          final ltA = countLeftTop(width, height, el.startAnchorId);
          final ltB = countLeftTop(width, height, el.endAnchorId);
          paint.color = Colors.red;
          paint.strokeWidth = 2.5;

          // Linia przerywana
          drawDashedLine(canvas, ltA, ltB, paint, 5.0, -1.0);

          // Rysowanie strzałki
          final arrowPath = Path();
          arrowPath.moveTo(ltB.dx, ltB.dy);

          final angle = math.atan2(ltB.dy - ltA.dy, ltB.dx - ltA.dx);
          final arrowLength = 6.0;

          final arrowPoint1 = Offset(
            ltB.dx - math.cos(angle + math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
            ltB.dy - math.sin(angle + math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
          );
          final arrowPoint2 = Offset(
            ltB.dx - math.cos(angle - math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
            ltB.dy - math.sin(angle - math.pi / 6) * arrowLength,
          );

          arrowPath.lineTo(arrowPoint1.dx, arrowPoint1.dy);
          arrowPath.lineTo(arrowPoint2.dx, arrowPoint2.dy);
          arrowPath.close();

          canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);
        } else if (el.type == 2) {
          //RYSOWANIE cienkiej linii ciągłej
          final ltA = countLeftTop(width, height, el.startAnchorId);
          final ltB = countLeftTop(width, height, el.endAnchorId);
          paint.color = darkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
          paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
          canvas.drawLine(ltA, ltB, paint);
        } else if (el.type == 3) {
          //RYSOWANIE cienkiej przerywanej lini czerwonej
          final ltA = countLeftTop(width, height, el.startAnchorId);
          final ltB = countLeftTop(width, height, el.endAnchorId);
          paint.color = Colors.red;
          paint.strokeWidth = 3.0;
          drawDashedLine(canvas, ltA, ltB, paint, 5.0, -1.0);
        } else if (el.type == 4) {
        //RYSOWANIE kropki
        final lt = countLeftTop(width, height, el.anchorId);
        paint.color = darkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
        paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
        canvas.drawCircle(lt, 4.0, paint);
     } else if (el.type == 5) {
        //RYSOWANIE kwadratu
        final lt = countLeftTop(width, height, el.anchorId);
        paint.color = darkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
        paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
        final size = 4.0;
        final rect = Rect.fromCenter(
          center: lt,
          width: size * 2,
          height: size * 2,
        );
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
      }
```

Then I try to show this in my other class:

```
    class ListViewAdapterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    final XmlModel xmlModel;
    const ListViewAdapterWidget({Key? key, required this.xmlModel})
      : super(key: key);

    [..]
    Container(
      width: 100,
      height:
        100,
      child: GraphicsClass.createCellWidget(
        kratka, context),
    ),
    [..]
```

This is screen:
[image]

BUT I'm having trouble adding any image (png, svg...) to this canvas. One egzample is below:

```
    if (el.type == 9) {
    final imgPath = 'assets/images/9_${el.shapeId}.png';
    final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load(imgPath);
    final Uint8List bytes = imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    final lt = countLeftTop(width, height, el.anchorId);
    final left = lt.dx - 15;
    final top = lt.dy - 15;

    canvas.drawImage(
      image,
      Offset(left.toDouble(), top.toDouble()),
      paint,
      );
    }
```

I always have same error:
*"StateError (Bad state: A Dart object attempted to access a native peer, but the native peer has been collected (nullptr). This is usually the result of calling methods on a native-backed object when the native resources have already been disposed.)"*

I want to add an image to my canvas but I don't know how to escape this problem. I try many ideas, solutions, even chatGPT ;) but still no result.
There are some solutions, but they must old and unrelated to my situation (I think).

I also tried like this:

```
    final lt = countLeftTop(width, height, el.anchorId);
    final left = lt.dx - 15;
    final top = lt.dy - 15;

    final String assetPath = 'assets/images/9_${el.shapeId}.png';
    final ByteData bytes =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).load(assetPath);
    final Uint8List byteList = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    final image = await decodeImageFromList(byteList);

    final srcRect = Rect.fromLTRB(
      0,
      0,
      image.width.toDouble(),
      image.height.toDouble(),
    );

    final dstRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
    left.toDouble(),
    top.toDouble(),
    image.width.toDouble(),
    image.height.toDouble(),
    );
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, srcRect, dstRect, Paint());
```

Comment: seems like `paint` method cannot be `async` - you have to load your `Image`s in some external context and pass them to your custom painter - like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332956/how-to-create-an-infinite-rain-of-icons-in-flutter#71347939 for example

Comment: But when I comment _if (el.type == 9)_ everything working good when paint is in async. Problem is only with Image... External context... you mean run this part from external method in CellPainter class?

Comment: ok, to verify comment out `if (el.type == 9) ...` but add at least one `await`, for example `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {})`

Comment: for "external context" check the link I posted

Comment: Thank you @pskink ! You really help me. Another example is here: [link](https://gist.github.com/netsmertia/9c588f23391c781fa1eb791f0dce0768) Now I can see all images in proper position, but I have a problem with other thing.