# electrons animation using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I create an animation like this in Flutter? I attempted to use AnimatedPositioned,but I encountered difficulty animating more than one circular container (represented by the electrons in the GIF).i want to use AnimatedPositioned to animate a circular container over an SVG image. Specifically, I aim to create an animation of an electrical circuit. but i can't make electrons animation like         GIF [electrons animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2s7c.gif)

Comment: the easiest way is to use `CustomPaint`

Comment: @pskink but the custompaint for drawing, i mean which widget in flutter is suitable for this type of animation part in GiF or a simple way to make this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2s7c.gif

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332956/how-to-create-an-infinite-rain-of-icons-in-flutter#71347939 pay attention to `super(repaint: ...)`

Answer (score 2):

#### After Edit:

Credits to pskink for this solution. It works for any square/rectangle sizes.

[See DartPad Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ae2a2f301a7110305b554c5e3e9bfc2d)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late FooPainter _fooPainter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), //Animation speed
    )..repeat();
    _fooPainter = FooPainter(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Animated Dots'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
          painter: _fooPainter,
          size: const Size(400, 300),
            ),  //Animation square/rectangle shape
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class FooPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FooPainter(this.animation) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation animation;
  PathMetric? metric;
  final p = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.blue;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Draw the background shape
    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.transparent; // Set your desired background color
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), backgroundPaint);

    const double borderWidth = 22.0; // Width of the border

  // Draw borders along the edges
  final borderPaint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.grey
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = borderWidth;

  final borderRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      borderWidth / 2, borderWidth / 2,
      size.width - borderWidth, size.height - borderWidth);
  canvas.drawRect(borderRect, borderPaint);

  if (metric == null) {
    final r = borderRect.deflate(0); // Adjust padding here
    final path = Path()..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(r, const Radius.circular(0)));
    metric = path.computeMetrics().first;
  }
  final m = metric!;
  final numDots = (m.length / 20.0).floor();
  final distanceBetweenDots = m.length / numDots;
  for (int i = 0; i < numDots; i++) {
    final distance = distanceBetweenDots * (i + animation.value);
    canvas.drawCircle(m.getTangentForOffset(distance)!.position, 6, p);
  }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FooPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

#### Before Edit:

Solution without CustomPaint that works for square only.

[See DartPad Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1a0b334c6cb4d671319e5ad0ce8582d8).

```html
class AnimatedDotMovingContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedDotMovingContainer({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimatedDotMovingContainer> createState() =>
      _AnimatedDotMovingContainerState();
}

class _AnimatedDotMovingContainerState extends State<AnimatedDotMovingContainer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  double dotSize = 20.0; 
  double containerSize = 250.0;
  int numBalls = 10; // Number of balls

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), //Speed of balls
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  double _getSquarePositionX(double value) {
    value = (value % 1); // Use % to keep value within [0, 1]
    if (value < 0.25) {
      return 1 - value * 4;
    } else if (value < 0.5) {
      return 0;
    } else if (value < 0.75) {
      return (value - 0.5) * 4;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  double _getSquarePositionY(double value) {
    value = (value % 1);
    if (value < 0.25) {
      return 0;
    } else if (value < 0.5) {
      return (value - 0.25) * 4;
    } else if (value < 0.75) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 1 - (value - 0.75) * 4;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Animated Dot Moving Container'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: containerSize,
          height: containerSize,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: dotSize),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
              for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++)
                Positioned(
                  left: (containerSize - dotSize) *
                      _getSquarePositionX(
                          _controller.value - i / numBalls), // Adjust position
                  top: (containerSize - dotSize) *
                      _getSquarePositionY(
                          _controller.value - i / numBalls), // Adjust position
                  child: Container(
                    width: dotSize,
                    height: dotSize,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                  width: 30.0,
                  child: Placeholder(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The formula with the AnimationController controls the counter-clockwise movement. If you want the dots to move to the opposite direction, simply adjust the formula:


double _getSquarePositionX(double value) {
  value = (value % 1); // Use % to keep value within [0, 1]
  if (value < 0.25) {
    return value * 4;
  } else if (value < 0.5) {
    return 1;
  } else if (value < 0.75) {
    return 1 - (value - 0.5) * 4;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: very good solution, I think it's best if you use `i / numBalls` rather then `i * .1` in case he want to change `numBalls` count

Comment: very nice catch I edited my answer to fix that

Comment: @Texv thank you , it's the best method for me.

Comment: @Texv one last question, when I make the movement in a rectangular shape not square i found the equally vertical distances between each container is less than the equally horizontal distances between each container and also the vertical animation speed is less than the horizontal animation speed so i want to make the speed constant along the rectangle and the distances between each container along the rectangle is equal, exactly as the square

Comment: you're right, my solution works best for square or a small-difference rectangle. If I change `containerSize` to `containerWidth` and `containerHeight` and apply them to `left` and `top` `position`, theres a difference in distancing and speed. This will require a different formula and approach. I think `CustomPainter` would work best for a rectangle like @pskink suggested, but I cant work it out for now. I don't have much experience with paint.

Comment: Thanks for that :) you should post it so they can mark it as the right answer. How do you add a background along the animated dots btw? When I add a background or bordersides I find a big padding/margin between the borders and the animated dots

Comment: @pskink https://dartpad.dev/?id=ae2a2f301a7110305b554c5e3e9bfc2d

Comment: @Texv you mean: `final r = borderRect; // Adjust padding here`?

Comment: @pskink haha don't know how i missed that, amazing solution! you deserve to get the correct answer so go ahead and post it :)

Comment: @Texv check my answer that animates colored dots along the rounded rectangle

Answer (score 1):

the easiest and the most efficient solution (since no `setState` is used at all and no rebuild is needed for every animation frame) is to use `CustomPaint` widget with passing an `AnimationController` as `repaint` parameter to `CustomPainter` (this is done in `FooPainter` constructor: `super(repaint: ctrl)`), to make the drawing logic easier `AnimationController.unbounded` is used and to make infinite animation `animateWith()` method is called

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Foo> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final ctrl = AnimationController.unbounded(vsync: this);
  bool running = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    toggleRunning();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: FooPainter(ctrl),
      child: Center(
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: toggleRunning,
          child: const Text('start / stop\nanimation', textScaleFactor: 1.5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void toggleRunning() {
    running = !running;
    // const endDistance = 100.0 * 60; // 60 sec animation
    const endDistance = double.infinity; // infinite animation
    final simulation = GravitySimulation(0, ctrl.value, endDistance, 100);
    running? ctrl.animateWith(simulation) : ctrl.stop();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ctrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class FooPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FooPainter(this.ctrl) : super(repaint: ctrl);

  final AnimationController ctrl;
  late PathMetric metric;
  late Path path;
  Size size = Size.zero;
  final p0 = Paint();
  final p1 = Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 1
    ..color = Colors.black87;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (this.size != size) {
      this.size = size;
      final r = Offset.zero & size;
      path = Path()..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(r.deflate(24), const Radius.circular(32)));
      metric = path.computeMetrics().first;
    }
    final numDots = (metric.length / 25.0).floor();
    final distanceBetweenDots = metric.length / numDots;
    canvas.drawPath(path, p1);
    for (int i = 0; i < numDots; i++) {
      final distance = (distanceBetweenDots * i + ctrl.value) % metric.length;
      // final color = HSVColor.fromAHSV(1, 360 * (i / numDots), 1, 1).toColor();
      final color = i.isEven? Colors.blue.shade900 : Colors.blue.shade500;
      final tangent = metric.getTangentForOffset(distance)!;
      canvas
        ..drawCircle(tangent.position, 8, p0..color = color.withOpacity(0.85))
        ..drawCircle(tangent.position, 8 - p1.strokeWidth / 2, p1);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FooPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```