How to draw thousands of points onto a canvas in real time?
The short question is: How do you draw thousands of colored points onto a canvas in real time?
But the situation is a little complex. Right now, the data structure looks like this:
class Point {
  final Offset position;
  final Color color;

  Point({required this.position, required this.color});
}

... which gets drawn by a CustomPainter in a for loop:
for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
  _pointPaint.color = allPointsOfChart[i].color;
  canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [allPointsOfChart[i].position], _pointPaint);
}

When drawing 3000 points on a three years old, low end (~120Euro) Android 12 phone, the above code keeps the rasterizer busy for 18-22 milliseconds.
Problems is, 3000 points ain't enough and 22 milliseconds are too long.
Caching the paint operations by drawing onto a background Canvas, will unfortunately not work because of the dynamic nature of the data.
Also, the order of the points is important, hence sorting the points by color and painting them in batches can't be done neither.
So..., the question is, is it even possible to draw, lets say, 10k points in real time in a CustomPainter? If not, could it be accomplishable using a custom shader?
Any advise on how you would approach this is very appreciated. Thank you!

tried draw[Raw]Atlas already?

and if you want real time updates (on every rendering frame and without rebuilding the whole widget tree) check how SpritePainter uses super(repaint: ...)  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332956/how-to-create-an-infinite-rain-of-icons-in-flutter/71347939#71347939

@pskink Wow! That lead to some spectacular performance gains: 25K points in, on avg, 5ms using drawRawAtlas()! Thank you very much for sharing this!

25k in 5ms? hmmm, to be honest i didn't expect that.. ;-)

Sorry, was an Android 13 (still super cheap, low end) device that painted the 25k points in 5ms. The one year older, also very low end Android 12 takes about 15ms for 25k points. Still amazing gains! Thank you.

sure, your welcome, compared to 18-22ms for 3k points ....still good (~10x faster) - try to optimize offsets and transform lists as i wrote in my answer, but ... it may not help much much

btw now i noticed you used drawRawAtlas instead of drawAtlas - did it make any difference in performance?

@pskink Sorry! I forgot to follow. Your pointer to drawRawAtlas() was just exactly what was needed. Much more efficient than starting with custom shaders... Thank you very much for your help!

@pskink Haven't tried drawAtlas(), because drawRawAtlas() appeared to be more suitable for performance optimization. The previous drawPoints() approach was already optimized until the ideas run out, but it still just didn't cut it. Anyway, the performance gain is pretty awesome. Thank you!

in my answer i was skeptical if drawRawAtlas makes big difference since actually i used both and i did not see any difference - but most likely it was so since i run both versions on flutter desktop linux, thats why i was curious how it looks on android, maybe on mobile platform (android, ios) the difference is more visible

you could use Canvas.drawAtlas (or even Canvas.drawRawAtlas but i dont think it will give you much better results)
short explanation:

first we need ui.Image that is required by Canvas.drawAtlas method - we could get it by decoding some .png or .webp image but the easier way is to use ui.PictureRecorder, pass it to ui.Canvas constructor and draw your "point"
rects lists contains in every position the same Rect:  starting at offset (0, 0) and with the size equal to image size
the main idea in this solution is to use BlendMode.dstATop so even if our ui.Image is completely black BlendMode.dstATop replaces its non transparent black pixels with a color that is specified in colors list (this makes possible to use any color for any "point")

the code:
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Foo())));

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Foo> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Durations.extralong4 * 3);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => controller.forward(from: 0),
          child: Text('animate for ${controller.duration!.inMilliseconds}ms'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: FooPainter(controller),
              child: const SizedBox.expand(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FooPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FooPainter(this.controller) : super(repaint: controller) {
    final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final canvas = Canvas(recorder);

    // different shapes of 'point':
    (switch (1) {
      // filled circle
      0 => const ShapeDecoration(color: Colors.black, shape: CircleBorder()),
      // outlined circle
      1 => const ShapeDecoration(shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: R * 0.6))),
      // 8-pointed star
      _ => const ShapeDecoration(color: Colors.black, shape: StarBorder(points: 8, innerRadiusRatio: 0.6)),
    })
      .createBoxPainter(() {})
      .paint(canvas, Offset.zero, const ImageConfiguration(size: Size.fromRadius(R)));

    image = recorder.endRecording().toImageSync((2 * R).ceil(), (2 * R).ceil());
  }

  static const R = 6.0; // radius
  static const D = 3.0; // delta +/-
  static const N = 1000;

  final AnimationController controller;
  late ui.Image image;
  final rnd = Random();
  List<ui.Offset>? offsets;
  final rects = List.filled(N, Offset.zero & const Size.fromRadius(R));
  final colors = List.generate(N, (i) => HSVColor.fromAHSV(1, 120 * i / N, 1, 0.8).toColor());

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    offsets ??= [ // initialize offsets
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        Offset(rnd.nextDouble() * size.width, rnd.nextDouble() * size.height)
    ];
    if (controller.isAnimating) {
      offsets = [ // update offsets by random delta
        ...offsets!.mapIndexed((i, o) {
          final factor = D * ui.lerpDouble(1, 2, colors[i].green / 255)!;
          final x = (o.dx + factor * ui.lerpDouble(-1, 1, rnd.nextDouble())!).clamp(0.0, size.width);
          final y = (o.dy + factor * ui.lerpDouble(-1, 1, rnd.nextDouble())!).clamp(0.0, size.height);
          return Offset(x, y);
        })
      ];
    }
    List<ui.RSTransform> transforms = [
      ...offsets!.map((o) => ui.RSTransform(1, 0, o.dx - R, o.dy - R))
    ];
    canvas.drawAtlas(image, transforms, rects, colors, BlendMode.dstATop, null, Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}


Got it working nicely with drawRawAtlas(). Thank you very much!
