How to properly position widgets using Stack in Flutter for responsive design?
I am building a splash screen for my Flutter app, and I'm having trouble positioning text and branding elements responsively on the screen. Specifically, I want to:

Position my app logo text ("NewApp") in the top-left corner.
Place the main branding ("SplashScreen") centered on the screen.
Add a description text below the main branding, centered horizontally.

I tried using Column with padding, but the layout isn't consistent across different screen sizes. I switched to using Stack and Positioned to gain better control over the positions, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to handle responsive layouts.
this is code:
class _SplashscreenbrandingState extends State<Splashscreenbranding> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.20),
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "New",
                      style: GoogleFonts.bakbakOne(
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF273272),
                          fontSize: 8,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "App",
                      style: GoogleFonts.bakbakOne(
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 8, 6, 4),
                          fontSize: 8,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: const Offset(0, -12),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Splash",
                    style: GoogleFonts.bakbakOne(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 187, 9, 134),
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Screen",
                    style: GoogleFonts.bakbakOne(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 57, 8, 172),
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(0, -15),
          child: Text(
              "Now your companies & employees are \nin one place and always under control",
              style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.7),
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              )),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

I expecting this:

Any suggestions or improvements on positioning widgets effectively would be much appreciated!

yes, you should use Stack widget for cases like this

@pskink  Can we array[runTimeIndex] on frag.shader for flutter , I am trying to get specific item but it is showing expression is needed to be const in shader.  purpose is to create NxN grid and providing specific color for each grid. is it possible ?

This is the fragmentShader and trying to pass from here , the goal is to create Game of Life  @pskink

@Md.YeasinSheikh  oooops custom shaders.... sorry, wrong address - i only know that such animals exist, but nothing more ;-(, btw do you have to use those custom shaders?

ok thanks anyway, I wonder where should I go now. currently creating image to handle the performance for large scale.

@pskink was experimenting to get the better performance

@Md.YeasinSheikh i mean you cannot live without that custom shader? and only use existing Canvas api? what performance problems do you have? what are you drawing in your CustomPainter?

canvas api is still expensive for [500x500] grids? I found it kinda laggy and takes time to render on customPaint. or I wonder was it because of the algorithm side-effect, will test again

@Md.YeasinSheikh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78764138/how-to-draw-thousands-of-points-onto-a-canvas-in-real-time/78769595#78769595 btw you dont draw the whole 500x500 grid on a display that is 1000x2000 pixels? unless the every grid item is 2x4 pixels but i dont think its the case...

Ok thanks, will play with it

@Md.YeasinSheikh btw also check https://gist.github.com/pskink/b86f5de25dd51d3b24f3994dea031357 - run the last last example called "tile display"

Yea this is cool but I didn't get magical_pattern

@pskink seems expensive for cpu, crashed with large number. 100k. I thinking about how much it can handle and rendering on gpu, skip the realTime ig

@Md.YeasinSheikh "magical pattern" are two Base64 encoded webp images

@Md.YeasinSheikh if Canvas.drawRawAtlas not helps then, yes, you will have to fight with custom shaders ;-(, btw if you are on master branch (or even beta, i dont know) you can try this: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-started-with-flutter-gpu-f33d497b7c11

oh no,,  this is what I have been seeking for,  branch doesn't matter; why flutter trying to do everything, it is getting harder to keep track and learn stuffs

Why don't you convert those widgets into an image instead...? And then displaying it with flutter_native_splash plugin? It will not change the layout and will be consistent.
Here's the link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash
